# SQL ORDER BY WHEN TIES

Tags: mysql, sql

I am organizing by points, but if there is a tie score I want it organized alphabetically

```
group by points
ORDER BY avg_points DESC, last_name DESC;
```

It does not seem to work correctly. That I am receiving scores with a tied average points, but not ordered correctly by last name. For example, I would have Adams before Smith if they both had a score of 5 points.

Comment: `DESC` means _descending_. I.e. you are asking for Smith before Adams. If you want Adams before Smith, switch to `ASC`.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL ordering of alphabetical data, `DESC` goes from Z-A, `ASC` goes from A-Z. Try this:

```
group by points
ORDER BY avg_points DESC, last_name ASC;
```

Comment: Are you sure about that @Akina? The original problem is "I am receiving scores with a tied average points, but not ordered correctly by last name. For example, I would have Adams before Smith if they both had a score of 5 points". They aren't looking for a TOP N like your comment to the question suggests

Comment: *They aren't looking for a TOP N like your comment to the question suggests* Mmm... maybe you're right... Please make some minor edition to your answer (add a space for example) for downvote remove.